# Integration by parts in first term of general linear, second order boundary value problem multiplied by test function v

Tags: integration

## Problem

The first term of a general linear, second order boundary value problem multiplied by test function $v \in H_0^1$ in 1D and then integrated over the domain $[a, b]$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\int_a^b -\frac{d}{dx}(p(x) \frac{du}{dx})v(x) = \int_a^b - \frac{d}{dx}(p \frac{du}{dx}) v, \tag{1}
\end{equation}

and can be integrated by parts for which the result is

\begin{equation}
\left[-p \frac{du}{dx} v \right]_a^b + \int_a^b p \frac{du} {dx}\frac{dv}{dx}. \tag{2}
\end{equation}

**Which parts of equation (1) correspond to $f$ and $dg$ for the integration by parts equation given below?**

\begin{equation}
\int f\ dg = fg - \int g\ df
\end{equation}

Note that the result provided in equation (2) is from section 3.2.2 in "Finite Element Methods: A Practical Guide" (Whiteley 2017).

## Attempt

It seems $f = v \implies df = \frac{dv}{dx}$ and $dg = -\frac{d}{dx}(p \frac{du}{dx}) = -\frac{dp}{dx}\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2} \implies g = \int -\frac{dp}{dx}\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2} = -p \frac{du}{dx}$ but I am a bit skeptical about applying the $\frac{d}{dx}$ on both $p$ and $\frac{du}{dx}$ in $dg$ because I don't think this is a valid operation (i.e., I would expect that the product rule would apply instead). Any pointers would be appreciated since I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to attempt to calculate $\frac{d}{dx}\left(p \frac{du}{dx}\right)$, just use the fact that $\int \frac{d}{dx}\left(h(x)\right)\, dx =h(x)$ (i.e. $\int$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$ "cancel each other out"). So $$\begin{align*}\frac{dg}{dx} &= -\frac{d}{dx}\left(p \frac{du}{dx}\right)\\\Rightarrow g &= -\int \frac{d}{dx}\left(p \frac{du}{dx}\right)\,dx \\ &= -p\frac{du}{dx}.\end{align*}$$

(As an aside, if you wanted to expand $\frac{d}{dx}\left(p \frac{du}{dx}\right)$, you would have to use the product rule.)

Comment: This makes sense! I knew I was overlooking something simple.